# altering order of list c++

Tags: c++, function, oop, pointers, iterator

if I have a list of items defined, and I wanted to change or change the order one of the chosen items to go up in the list, how do i implement that?

The definition of the function should be as follows:

```
items* shift_back(item* head, int i){
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: In `if(k == 1 && prevCons != nullptr)` the condition `prevCons != nullptr` will *never* be true.

Comment: On a different note, brace-enclosed statement blocks (`{}`) doesn't need to be terminated with a semicolon `;`. Which you seem to know because you don't do it for the `for` loop, only the `if`. How come?

Answer (score 1):

Assume this is your list:

```
      +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+
      |11| -|->|22| -|->|33| -|->|44| -|->|55| -|->nullptr
      +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+
         1        2        3        4        5     [k represents position of a node]
```

- If the value of `k` is `2` (i.e. move up `2`<sup>nd</sup> node) then you only need information about it's previous node which is first node and after moving `2`<sup>nd</sup> node up, it will become first node.

  ```
    [k - 1] -> [k] -> [k + 1] -> [k + 1] -> .....
    -------     |
       |        +- This node next pointer need to set to [k - 1]
       +- This node next pointer need to set to [k + 1] 

    // after moving up kth position node 

    [k] -> [k - 1] -> [k + 1] -> [k + 1] -> .....

   example [k = 2]:
      +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+
      |22| -|->|11| -|->|33| -|->|44| -|->|55| -|->nullptr
      +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+
  ```
- If the value of `k` is greater than `2` (any node after `2`<sup>nd</sup> node), you need information about previous two nodes of node at location `k`.

  ```
    [k - 3] -> [k - 2] -> [k - 1] -> [k] -> [k + 1] -> [k + 1] -> .....
               -------    -------     |
                  |          |        +- This node next pointer need to set to [k - 1]
                  |          +- This node next pointer need to set to [k + 1]
                  +- This node next pointer need to set to [k]

     // after moving up kth position node up

    [k - 3] -> [k - 2] -> [k] -> [k - 1] -> [k + 1] -> [k + 1] -> .....

   example [k = 4]:
      +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+
      |11| -|->|22| -|->|44| -|->|33| -|->|55| -|->nullptr
      +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+  +-----+
  ```
- If the value of `k` is less than or equal to `1` or any value beyond the length of list then the list should remain unaltered.

Keeping the above points in mind, you can do:

```
consumer* move_up (consumer* head, int k) {
    consumer* ll = head;
    consumer* prev = nullptr;

    for (int i = 1; (i < k - 1) && (ll != nullptr); ++i) {
        prev = ll;
        ll = ll->next;
    }

    if ((k > 1) && (ll != nullptr) && (ll->next != nullptr)) {
        consumer* x = ll->next;
        ll->next = ll->next->next;
        x->next = ll;
        ll = x;
    }

    if (prev != nullptr) {
        prev->next = ll;
        ll = head;
    }

    return ll;
}
```

A few suggestions:

- Avoid using raw pointers, instead use [Smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Smart_pointers).
- Make yourself aware of `C++` [Containers Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). `std::forward_list` may be of your interest.